# Excel 2019 VBA SaveAs generates runtime 1004

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I want to save an Excel file to XLMS.

In office 2010 - 2016 this code works but in 2019 I get runtime error 1004.

I searched the internet for a solution.

I get the error on the SaveAs line.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim NewFileFilter As String
Dim myTitle As String
Dim FileSaveName As Variant
Dim NewFileFormat As Long

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

NewFileName = "Test.xlsm"
NewFileFilter = "Excel Macro-Enabled workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm"
NewFileFormat = 52

myTitle = "Navigate to the required folder"

FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
         (InitialFileName:=NewFileName, _
          filefilter:=NewFileFilter, _
          Title:=myTitle)

If Not FileSaveName = False Then
    Wb.SaveAs FileName:=FileSaveName, _
                 FileFormat:=NewFileFormat
    'Call PDF_PRINT

Else

    'MsgBox "File NOT Saved. User cancelled the Save."
    X = MsgBox("ExcelFile NOT Saved.User cancelled the Save." & vbCrLf & _
      "Click CANCEL to abort pdf-save function as well." & vbCrLf & _
      "Or click OK to proceed with the pdf-saving function.", vbOKCancel, _
      "EXCEL SAVE FUNCTION")

    If X = vbOK Then PDF_PRINT Else Exit Sub

End If
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: Always on the line  Wb.SaveAs FileName:=FileSaveName, _

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it is working to save a PDF for me.

```
Sub MacroTest()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim NewFileFilter As String
Dim myTitle As String
Dim FileSaveName As Variant
Dim NewFileFormat As Long

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

NewFileName = "Test.xlsm"
NewFileFilter = "Excel Macro-Enabled workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm"
NewFileFormat = 52

myTitle = "Navigate to the required folder"

FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
         (InitialFileName:=NewFileName, _
          filefilter:=NewFileFilter, _
          Title:=myTitle)

If Not FileSaveName = False Then
   Wb.SaveAs Filename:=FileSaveName, _
                 FileFormat:=NewFileFormat
   Call PDF_Print

Else

   'MsgBox "File NOT Saved. User cancelled the Save."
   X = MsgBox("ExcelFile NOT Saved.User cancelled the Save." & vbCrLf & "Click CANCEL to abort pdf-save function as well." & vbCrLf & "Or click OK to proceed with the pdf-saving function.", vbOKCancel, "EXCEL SAVE FUNCTION")

End If

End Sub

Sub PDF_Print()

    Dim strPth As String, strFile As String

    strPth = "C:\"
    strFile = "Test.pdf"

    'If X = vbOK Then PrintPDF Else Exit Sub

  If X = vbOK Then PrintPDF(0, strPth & strFile) Then
  MsgBox "Printing failed"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not the PDF creation i have problem with.
It's the save to XLSM that is not working.
The code is a part of a bigger script and later in it i save to PDF also.
But this is not the problem.